# Is Firebase appropriate in pwa with offline mode?

Tags: ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

I'm developing a PWA with Ionic/angular and Firebase/Firestore.
It manage a collection of categorized lyrics. Admins can add/delete/modify lyrics etc. Firestore is very usefull for that.

I want my PWA fully accessible offline after installation. To do that i need to read all collection (300 documents) when app loads in order to cache it. It is an important amount of reads by user, Google charge 300 reads each time app is loaded, and even more with listeners with database changes. I think, my use case is not very adapted to Firestore way to get data.

```
const lyricsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Lyric> = this.afStore.collection<Lyric>('lyrics', ref => ref.orderBy('title'));

this.lyrics$ = lyricsCollection.snapshotChanges();
```

My question is: How can i improve my db or app architecture to be more adapted to my needs ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Sure, it is a very generic question on firebase paradigm but i edited my question with a sample